# programming a stopwatch

Tags: .net, javascript

i would like to make a site that is like this one:

http://www.online-stopwatch.com/

i know a vb.net and little bit of everything else and am wondering what is the best platform to use to make this and how i can start to make this stopwatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use javascript. There is nothing here that is so fancy that it can't be done completely on the client side.

Comment: mishka, what about second part of q?

Comment: what about it? Do you have any experience programming? If not, I would first pick up a book or read some online javascript tutorials. I'm not sure what else to tell you other than you start at the beginning :-)

Answer (score 2):

The link posted was coded using Flash.

The reason it works well, is that it does not have to postback to the server.  All of the work is done client-side.

Something similar could be done using Javascript and HTML as that is a client-side technology.

ASP.NET is a *server-side* technology.  It may be possible to use an ASP.NET AJAX Asynchronous timer to accomplish something similiar, however, due to the fact that it would have to postback to the server, it certainly would not be as smooth as the client-side technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you do it in Flash. Would probably be much more accurate than doing it within the browser with javascript.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd say that? What makes Flash more accurate?

Comment: asp.net is related more to server side programming. Things like Javascript, Jquery, flash etc... are more suited for this type of app (client-side)

Comment: Here ya go: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

With JS you are at the mercy of the browser's somewhat unreliable timing capabilities. Flash would at least be a bit more consistent

Comment: Interesting. Insightful link you posted there. Though I suppose if you need accuracy within 15ms, you're not going to be using an internet stopwatch to measure it!

Comment: @Mike Sherov - Flash is backed by an ActiveX control. ActiveX controls have access to operating system level calls which mean they could call Win32 API timer functions for example. Javascript, an interpreted language, has higher overhead than a compiled ActiveX control. (Whether or not Flash calls Win32 API functions, I don't know, but it is a viable option.) http://www.vbworkshop.com/Chapters/ch10g.htm

Comment: Good point Mike! :)

Though Roy, wouldn't the browser also have access to the Win32 API? I agree though, much more overhead associated with JS interpretation.

Comment: @ChrisDiRulli - Yes, the browser would also have access to the API however, Flash is compiled into byte code where-as Javascript is interpreted on the fly (as you suggest more overhead with JS interpretation).

Answer (score 1):

They are using adobe Flash. So you could use that.

VB.NET and ASP.NET won't really help you as this is all would have to be done client-side.